# React Native stylesheet not updating on value change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a Theme Context that exposes all the colors in my app, in light and dark mode. I just set this up and it works fine, but the styles don't get updated, even though the actual values are changing. I replicated it in Codesanbox and it does indeed work, but why not in my app?

[image: gif]

[Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leavitt-k43ep?file=/src/Switch.js)

Here are my files in my project (the problem is in `./pages/switcher.tsx`:

`./context/Theme.tsx`:

```js
const ThemeProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<ThemeOptions>('light')

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

`./hooks/useTheme.ts`:

```js
const useTheme = (): UseThemeHook => {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext)!

  if (theme === 'dark') {
    return {
      theme: darkTheme, // returns all colors
      setTheme, // along with the function to switch themes
    }
  }

  return {
    theme: lightTheme,
    setTheme,
  }
}
```

`./App.tsx`:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      // children
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

`./pages/switcher.tsx`:

```js
const Swither: React.FC<SwitherProps> = ({}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null>(null)
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme()

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(auth().currentUser)
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{ ...Layout.layout, ...Layout.default }}>
      {user ? (
        <>        // styles here do not update       but this text does
          <Text style={{ color: theme.text }}>Theme: {theme.text}</Text>
          <Switch
            trackColor={{ false: '#767577', true: '#81b0ff' }}
            thumbColor={enabled ? '#f5dd4b' : '#f4f3f4'}
            ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
            onValueChange={() => {
              setEnabled(!enabled)
              setTheme(value => (value === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'))
            }}
            value={enabled}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Text>User is null</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

All the files are available [here](https://github.com/herbievine/semeru/tree/main/src)

Comment: I just ran into this when I was implementing ui rotation based on device orientation, react native must be using the object passed to the style param similar to a state prop, since you're basically passing a static object react native doesnt see a reason to update the styling. In your useTheme hook I would return a 3rd property for the styles and recommend using react native's StyleSheet.create({}) function to create it

Comment: Well I modified my constants to 'red' and 'blue' and that worked fine. The I hardcoded the color of the text to {{ color: 'black' }} and nothing happened. So I think it's got something to do with how colors are displaying, not the actual code. I don't know where it's coming from or how to fix it though...

Comment: Ok you asked if you're going to shoot down suggestions then maybe not ask on a public forum